# Config file for lessc

Tags: css, node.js, less

I need to override a lot of less variables.
I run less with script like

```
lessc --js --modify-var=@layout-body-background=#ffffff pathFrom > pathTo
```

But it is pretty painful write there all the variables to modify.
Is there a way to write some kind of config and run in something like

```
lessc --config=./pathToMyConfig
```

Comment: You can create a separate file called variables-overrides.less and in there you override all the variables you need.

Comment: simple idea work. thx. anyway i would rather to use some config file for other configuration options.

Comment: So It will solve your problem ?

Comment: the main problem with override a lot of variables yes.

Comment: *A*. You can create your own [script invoking `less.render`](http://lesscss.org/usage/#programmatic-usage) (this is basically what `lessc` is itself) and put any options you want there. *B*. Every shell has a way to redirect an input from a file (e.g. for win cmd it would be something like `lessc < pathToYourConfigFile`, for other shells consult their docs). *C*. Create you own shell script (similar to `lessc.cmd`/`lessc.sh` invoked by default ).

Answer (score 1):

You can create a separate file called `variables-overrides.less` and in there you override all the variables you need

Comment: i upvoted your answer but i wont accept it since like i said i want to have config file where i can set additional options [see](http://lesscss.org/usage/).